Нашел библиотеку, где за мышкой двигается дым (react-fluid-distortion) как сделать так, чтобы дым был над элементами, в события мыши отрабатывались
Нашел библиотеку движения дыма за курсором (https://github.com/whatisjery/react-fluid-distortion?tab=readme-ov-file#readme), не понимаю как реализовать так, чтобы дым был над всем проектом, но события мыши (click, hover и тд) срабатывали обычным образом. Нужно решение для React/Next.js
